# Is it safe to delete the recovery partition?

Tags: partitioning, windows-10, disk-management

I am trying to grow my C: drive to use the unallocated space on Disk 0.

Is it safe to throw away the Recovery Partition (i.e. make it unallocated)? And if so, is GParted an ok tool to do that with?

Or do I need to move that, and if so, is the way to do that to reduce the size of the unallocated partition so there is empty space at the end, then move it there?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is safe to delete the recovery partition. You can use a Windows installation medium to use the recovery feature in the future, if needed.

But instead of a plain deletion, I recommend to disable the recovery environment from an elevated command prompt first:

```
reagentc /disable
```

so that your OS is aware that you don't want that partition. You can delete it afterwards. You can use GParted, but the onboard `diskpart` tool will do it already:

1. Execute `diskpart` in an elevated command prompt.
2. List your disks:

   ```
   list disk
   ```
3. Select your disk:

   ```
   select disk <NUMBER>
   ```
4. List the partitions on that disk:

   ```
   list partition
   ```
5. Select the recovery partition:

   ```
   select partition <NUMBER>
   ```
6. Delete the partition:

   ```
   delete partition override
   ```

   `override` is mandatory in order to delete a recovery partition.

Answer (score 1):

Recovery partition is a special partition on system hard drive and is used to restore the system to factory settings in the event of system issues. To protect recovery partition from being changed or deleted, recovery partition usually has no drive letter, and only a Help option is provided in Disk Management.

Yes, it is safe to remove the recovery partition.

You can use GParted, 3rd Party partition applications, or even from within Windows.

I suggest you read this [article](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/delete-recovery-partition.html), as it has some good information about this subject.