# How to Extend C drive from D: drive (SSD with NTFS bitlocker) and also there is Recovery Partiton in between two drives?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, windows-11, partition-recovery

I am using a HP fq1089AU laptop running

```
Edition Windows 11 Home Insider Preview Single Language
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎04-‎07-‎2023
OS build    23493.1000
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.23493.1000.0
```

[Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyZ4g.png)

I want to extend my c drive space, from the space in the d drive. I Browsed the internet and came to know that

> 1. I have to move the contents from D to a new drive(for example E:)
> 2. Delete D drive and delete the recovery partition using diskpart in cmd
> 3. and then Extend C to Unallocated space and rename E drive to D

I am having doubt that is it safe to use diskpart commands to delete the recovery partition, what will happen if I delete the recovery partition, Is there any other precaution I just need to follow?

[Reference Video](https://youtu.be/quQh9KgjQKk)

[Disk parition menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICtBO.png)

Comment: a) you have 2 recovery partitions - do you know why? b) I take it `E:` is a new disk

Comment: @JaromandaX a)  I don't know b)  Yes `E: ` drive will be the new drive to be created to move the contents from D to E

Comment: OK, so, when you first installed windows, did you create C: and D: - odd choice to make. I suspect you installed Windows on a ~120GB drive, then moved it over to the drive you have now, and created the new partition ... and have probably upgraded windows after that, maybe win 10 to win 11 - if that's the case, that middle recovery partition is probably for win10, so you can remove it safely

Comment: You’ll want to disable not suspend BitLocker protection before you perform any changes to your partitions

Comment: Actually i did not installed windows it came inbuilt as i purchased a laptop. which was installed on C: drive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to delete the recovery partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/1624160/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-recovery-partition)

Answer (score 0):

Might be, that this is true from your point of view:

```
Actually i did not installed windows it came inbuilt as i purchased a laptop.
```

But an OEM installation hardly will deliver an ***Insider Preview*** edition for an officially sold system:

> ```
> Edition Windows 11 Home Insider Preview Single Language
> ```

So I'm quite sure, someone

1. Upgraded a Windows 10 system without cleaning the original disk
   *=> So the Recovery Partition (583 MB) at the end of the disk survived.*
2. He was using a custom setup method to do this. This method  cloned the first three partitions (~ 120 GB) from a master media to your disk
3. Filled the free space by creating the drive D:
4. Made the system bootable by a repair tool like "bcdboot.exe"
5. Sold the computer to you.

If you want to be sure, you should check the recovery partitions for their content. I would assume:

- the 661 MB recovery partition in the middel contains "Windows 11 Home Insider Preview"
- The 583 MB recovery partition at the end is "Windows 10 Home"

But before you take these efforts you should decide:
Do you want to keep the *"Insider Prview"* or might it be better to use a regular release installation?

---

If you decide for a new release installation:

1. Decrypt your files by the BitLocker tools
2. Save (backup) your files to an external media
3. Go to [Microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11) to setup your USB pendrive with the current Windows 11 edition installer.
4. Verify you really have backed up all of your data.
5. Ideally you wipe your disk by an external USB-bootable toolkit or Linux.
6. If you skipped step 5 Windows Setup will ask. – Choose to do a clean/fresh install *without keeping data of an existing Windows*
7. The rest is done by the installation assistant.

---

Else if you want to keep the current installation, tell us and I update this answer to shift the partitions after requesting some more details.

Comment: Did this answer your question?